# Submitting separate IPAs for each iPhone model

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

My app has unique interface for each iPhone model. More specifically, there is a unique interface for each screen size. While I could embed everything in a single app, there are many unused assets. For instance, full screen image for iPhone 4S requires 1.76 MB, but IPA requires 12.63 MB for the same asset because it contains a separate image for each possible screen size.

Is it possible to submit separate IPA's for each iPhone model, where each includes only assets required for that specific iPhone?

Comment: This makes no sense. And no, you can't.

Comment: Also, there's like a 1,000% chance you can reduce the filesize of a single 4S background image down from 2MB if you export it with better settings.  Try reducing the filesizes of your images, and this problem goes away.

Comment: This makes *some* sense, but it's not how iOS and the app store work. So no, you can't.

Comment: simple answer: App will be rejected. It needs to work on all devices irrespective of screen size.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. The workflow Apple has built is to include all assets for every screen size. You use tools like autolayout to show and hide things based on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

please change your project to support auto-loayout or handle view programmatically.

what you intended wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to (or are able to), have multiple .ipa files for an app at one time. In fact, you've probably created more work for yourself then you actually needed to do by trying to do so.

Apple is now encouraging developers to embrace Adaptive User Interfaces. As their [guide](https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/) states, "With the latest advancements with View Controllers in iOS 8 and Auto Layout in Xcode, it’s now even easier for you to adapt your user interface to context and different sized devices". In other words, you only need a single storyboard for all iOS devices.

I would encourage you to do some more research on this concept, and adopt it for your app. This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial) should get you started.